# Masonry adds margin to elements after reload

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I have a problem with my Masonry gallery while using Bootstrap 3. Everytime I reload the page, there's a margin being added to every image in the grid. Any ideas what causes this and how to fix it?

Here's a video of it: https://youtu.be/1_HI_PZACeM

And here's my code:

```
<div id="gallery">          
    <div class="block">
        <img src="images/gallery/1.jpg">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
                    <p>Whaterver It Is - Always Awesome</p>
                </div><!-- end caption-text -->
            </div><!-- end caption -->
        </a>
    </div><!-- end block -->    
</div><!-- end #gallery -->

<style>
#gallery{
    background: #EEE;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;          
}       
.block{ 
    width: 20%;
    float: left; 
    background: #333;           
    overflow: hidden;       
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;     
}
.block img{
    height: auto; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 4;
}
.block:hover .caption{
    opacity: 1;
}
.block .caption{
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;       
    -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}
.block .blur{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
}   
.block .caption-text h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.block .caption-text{
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    top: 35%;       
}
</style>    

<script>
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $('div#gallery').masonry({
            columnWidth: '.block',
            itemSelector: '.block',             
            percentPosition: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `margin: 0;`and maybe also `line-height: 0px;` to the `.block` class' rules. When a container only contains an image, there is often a little bit of space at the bottom which `line-height: 0px;` can eliminate.

Comment: didn't help :/ i think it's in the masonry... maybe it's calculating the space between elements wrong..